# Hide mobile class

Tags: css

I have a problem trying to declare a CSS class which hides an element on a mobile device.

Recipes says to do this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
            .hidden-mobile { 
              display: none;
            }
          }
```

BUT, my mobile phone is 1080 x 2520 pixels so I have to increase to 1200. But how long will this work, when will a phone with 1600 pixels become standard?

Is there a more portable way to do this, that to look at the screen size?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to display none for all mobile devices you can target mobile devices with different ways.

```
@media (pointer:coarse) {
    /* Target for devices that uses touch" */
}

@media (hover: none) { 
   /* Target for the devices that can not hover */
}
```